# Flutter web Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, web, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect Firestore to my web project but it gives me "no firebase app has been created"
this is the way I used the script in the index file

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-------cnto--------------",
    authDomain: "---------.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "---------",
    storageBucket: "---------.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "---------48",
    appId: "1:---------48:web:---------89"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
```

and this is the way I initialize the app

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());

}
```

when I added await and async it waits forever and gives me a white screen like there is nothing to wait for

Comment: I suggest you read this page. FlutterFire CLI made it even easier to use Flutter: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli

Answer (score 2):

Setup the [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) and then run this in your terminal:

```
flutterfire configure
```

This tool is awesome and it makes it so you never have to touch native files again when setting up Firebase.

Comment: The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because every version of flutterfire_cli depends on xml >=5.3.0 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0,
  flutterfire_cli is forbidden.
So, because pub global activate depends on flutterfire_cli any, version solving failed.

Comment: It gives me this error, I run choco upgrade dart-SDK, and still the same message.

Comment: Change this in your pubspec.yaml: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.0 <3.0.0"